# Getting NULLs out of an entire table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, null

I have a SQL Server table that I am building with over 100 columns.  I am running `UPDATE TABLE_NAME` queries to populate that table.  However, if there are no records available, a `NULL` is inserted into the record.  This makes the calculations that I must perform difficult .

I tried creating the table with `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT (0)` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, but when I run an update, it tries to insert a NULL value and I get this error:

Update Statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET NumOrders = (SELECT count(OrderID) FROM ORDERS WHERE TABLE_NAME.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID);
```

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NumOrders', table 'TABLE_NAME'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.`

I could run a 2nd update query to remove the NULLS, such as:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET NumOrders = 0
WHERE NumOrders IS NULL;
```

This seems like I am doubling up on the update queries I have to write.

There has to be a better way to do this, right....?

Thanks

Comment: Does your table have over 100 columns?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the update you are doing that is causing the issue?

Comment: 100 columns? Sounds like a performance nightmare waiting to happen - Couldn't that be refactored?

Comment: @AdamKing King It's not a production table - It's purely for analysis.  That said - I'm not sure how I would refactor something like this.  The goal is to gather all possible customer data into a table to analyze.  Thoughts?

Comment: So its a data warehouse? If so you might want to consider Googling for a "Star Schema"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET NumOrders = isnull((SELECT count(OrderID) FROM ORDERS WHERE TABLE_NAME.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID),0);
```

does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

default constraints only fire on inserts not updates, another option for you is to have an update trigger that will change the NULLS to something that is not null

or specify the values in your update statement and make sure it is not null but an actual value

Comment: To ensure it's not a null in the update statement, would I just run a `CASE` for every update?  Is there function that would handle that rather than raw code?

Comment: wrap COALESCE() or ISNULL() around your values or variable/parameters

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NumOrders = COALESCE((SELECT count(OrderID) FROM ORDERS WHERE TABLE_NAME.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID),0);